# Issues plotting two lines with JSON data on high chart using Angular JS - name undefined

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Trying to plot a high chart dynamically using Angular JS. I have two lines I want to plot on the same graph.

Example item in the 'jsondata':

```
{
  "ID": 123456,
  "SaleDate": "2016-02",
  "SalesAgeBucket5": "NULL",
  "SalesAgeBucket10": 19300000,
  "SalesAgeBucket15": "NULL",
  "SalesAgeBucket20": "NULL",
  "SalesAgeBucket25": "NULL"
}
```

In the high chart config file the name is being applied in the series but not within the data attribute. So SalesAgeBucket5 is plotted with all the data but it is not being grouped. I am only seeing one line with all the data plotted against that series.

```
    $scope.chartConfig.series[0].name = "SalesAgeBucket5";
$scope.chartConfig.series[0].data  = jsondata.map(item => item["SalesAgeBucket5"]);
$scope.chartConfig.series[1].name = "SalesAgeBucket10";
$scope.chartConfig.series[1].data  = jsondata.map(item => item["SalesAgeBucket10"]);
$scope.chartConfig.xAxis.categories = jsondata.map(item => item[Object.keys(jsondata[0].SaleDate)]);
```

> ```
> > angular.min.js:124 TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
>     at b.$scope.getData (main.js:25699)
>     at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:242), <anonymous>:4:141)
>     at e (angular.min.js:288)
>     at b.$eval (angular.min.js:151)
>     at b.$apply (angular.min.js:151)
>     at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:288)
>     at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>     at HTMLSpanElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
> ```

Output of high chart config:

```
  {
   "chart":{
      
   },
   "plotOptions":{
      "line":{
         "dataLabels":{
            "enabled":false
         },
         "enableMouseTracking":true
      }
   },
   "series":[
      {
         "data":["null","null",140000,"null" etc... INCLUDES ALL VALUES],
         "id":"Results1",
         "turboThreshold":0,
         "name":"SalesAgeBucket5"
      }
   ],
   "xAxis":{
      "categories":""
   },
   "title":{
      "text":"Sales & Purchase"
   }
}
```

but I am expecting multiple line charts on this graph therefore multiple data attributes

Comment: Check the value in **$scope.chartConfig.series[1]**

Comment: I checked via console log and it says 'undefined'. Not sure why its not creating a second series, still cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your chart config, **series** array has only one element. There is nothing for "SalesAgeBucket10".
I do not have your code so cannot reproduce issue on my side but can suggest to try the following.
Modify series array in high chart config to:

```
"series":[
      {
         
         "id":"Results1",
         "turboThreshold":0,             
      },
      {
         
         "id":"Results2",
         "turboThreshold":0,             
      }
   ],
```

Comment: Exactly, if you want to create the chart with multiple lines you need to create multiple series like in the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zxskLo4h/.